# How to make right and left div go all the way to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, view

Ive got a home page. In the body div ive got three divs, a right div, a left div and a center div. In the center div i have the @renderbody that renders the specific views. I want the right and left div height to go all the way to the footer. How can I make the side divs the same height as the center div, going all the way down to the bottom to the footer div.

```
#body {
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

#body-main-left { 
    background-color:rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    height:auto;

}

#body-main-right {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    height:auto;
}

#body-main-center {
    margin: 0 150px 0 150px;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}


<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header-banner">
            HeaderBanner image will reside here
        </div>
        <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>


<li class='active'>@Html.ActionLink("", "", "")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("", "", "")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("", "", "")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("", "", "")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("", "", "")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="body-main-left">Left Block</div>
        <div id="body-main-right">Right Block</div>
        <div id="body-main-center">@RenderBody()</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Footer copyright
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have padding (10px) set to your `#body`, set the bottom padding to 0 should make it *go all the way to the footer*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example:**

https://jsfiddle.net/9vd83rww/5/

Add `padding-bottom: 0px;` to `#body` like this:

```
#body {
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox, your CSS could be something like this:

```
#body {
    background-color:white;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#body-main-left { 
    background-color:rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    width: 150px;
}

#body-main-right {
    background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1);
    width: 150px;
    order: 2;
}

#body-main-center {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#footer {
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}
```

Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tinmarin60/9h6tkaws/1/)